# Como crear un fondo que no sea cuadrado?

Tags: html, css

Quiero crear un fondo inclinado para que mi sitio sea mas atractivo en general.

Un ejemplo bastante claro es el fondo rojo que tiene este sitio ''https://ed.team/''.

Entre en su código css pero no encuentro en donde le pone forma a ese fondo.

Comment: usa un `clip-path: polygon(x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, x4 y4);` que recorta/enmascara el fondo  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Esta línea es la que hace la magia: clip-path: polygon(0 6%,100% 0,100% 94%,0 100%);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues inspeccionando el código, ellos tienen lo siguiente:

```
.main-main.main-front #block-escueladigital-content::before {
    content: "";
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 6%,100% 0,100% 94%,0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 6%,100% 0,100% 94%,0 100%);
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,60,50,.95),rgba(255,60,50,.95)),url(../img/edcamp-bogota-2017.jpg) center 40%/cover no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
}
```

Ahí se está usando la propiedad css [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), que, como se describe, recorta el div de fondo:

> La propiedad CSS clip-path previene que una porción de un elemento se
>   muestre definiendo una región de recorte para mostrarse, es decir,
>   **solo una parte específica del elemento se mostrará.**

Cada valor pasado a `polygon` dentro de `clip-path`, marcará la coordenada de un vértice del polígono, en este caso:

```
clip-path: polygon( esquinaSuperiorIzquierda (x, y),
                    esquinaSuperiorDerecha (x, y),
                    esquinaInferiorDerecha (x, y),
                    esquinaInferiorIzquierda (x, y) );
```